# Fail to upload code from Arduino IDE to Custom ESP32 WROOM 32 using Arduino Uno as ISP

Tags: c++, iot, arduino-uno, esp32, arduino-ide

**Here is Custom ESP32 WROOM 32 circuit diagram**

[Custom ESP32 WROOM 32 circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UvLx.png)

**Here is My Board Design**

[Single Layer Board Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/968Ku.png)

**Here are my Connection**

1. tx-tx
2. rx-rx
3. gnd-gnd
4. 3.3v - 3.3v

*I removed the Atmaga329p pu ic of arduino uno and connecting gnd with reset pin to acts as USB Serial Adapter*
[arduino uno as USB Serial Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecAn1.jpg)

**Uploading Process.....**

*System and Software Configuration *

> Window 10 64 bit,
> Arduino IDE 1.8.13,
> CP210xVCPInstaller_x64

*Code upload*

> Here is my arduino IDE > tool > board selection
> [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWTUs.png)

- Here is the data i received in the serial monitor when pressing boot button of esp32*
- > rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT) configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
- > clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
- > mode:DIO, clock div:2 load:0x3fff0018,len:4 load:0x3fff001c,len:5656
- > load:0x40078000,len:0 ho 12 tail 0 room 4 load:0x40078000,len:13844
- > entry 0x40078fc4 [0;32mI (30) boot: ESP-IDF v3.0.7 2nd stage
- > bootloader[0m [0;32mI (30) boot: compile time 09:04:31[0m [0;32mI
- > (30) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...[0m [0;32mI (35)
- > boot: SPI Speed      : 40MHz[0m [0;32mI (39) boot: SPI Mode       :
- > DIO[0m [0;32mI (43) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB[0m [0;32mI (47)
- > boot: Partition Table:[0m [0;32mI (51) boot: ## Label
- > Usage          Type ST Offset   Length[0m [0;32mI (58) boot:  0
- > phy_init         RF data          01 01 0000f000 00001000[0m
- > [0;32mI (65) boot:  1 otadata          OTA data         01 00
- > 00010000 00002000[0m [0;32mI (73) boot:  2 nvs              WiFi
- > data        01 02 00012000 0000e000[0m [0;32mI (80) boot:  3
- > at_customize     unknown          40 00 00020000 000e0000[0m
- > [0;32mI (88) boot:  4 ota_0            OTA app          00 10
- > 00100000 00180000[0m [0;32mI (95) boot:  5 ota_1            OTA app
- > 00 11 00280000 00180000[0m [0;32mI (103) boot: End of partition
- > table[0m [0;32mI (107) boot: No factory image, trying OTA 0[0m
- > [0;32mI (112) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00100020
- > vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x20614 (132628) map[0m [0;32mI (167)
- > esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x0012063c vaddr=0x3ffc0000 size=0x02d7c
- > ( 11644) load[0m [0;32mI (172) esp_image: segment 2:
- > paddr=0x001233c0 vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 (  1024) load[0m
- > [0;32mI (175) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x001237c8
- > vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x0c848 ( 51272) load[0m [0;32mI (204)
- > esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00130018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0xdfc80
- > (916608) map[0m [0;32mI (526) esp_image: segment 5:
- > paddr=0x0020fca0 vaddr=0x4008cc48 size=0x02504 (  9476) load[0m
- > [0;32mI (530) esp_image: segment 6: paddr=0x002121ac
- > vaddr=0x400c0000 size=0x00064 (   100) load[0m [0;32mI (541) boot:
- > Loaded app from partition at offset 0x100000[0m [0;32mI (541) boot:
- > Disabling RNG early entropy source...[0m
- > 1.1.3
- > I (590) wifi: wifi firmware version: 703e53b I (590) wifi: config NVS
- > flash: enabled I (590) wifi: config nano formating: disabled I (600)
- > wifi: Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32 I (601) wifi: Init data frame
- > dynamic rx buffer num: 32 I (601) wifi: Init management frame dynamic
- > rx buffer num: 32 I (606) wifi: wifi driver task: 3ffdeeb8, prio:23,
- > stack:3584 I (611) wifi: Init static rx buffer num: 10 I (615) wifi:
- > Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32 I (619) wifi: wifi power manager task:
- > 0x3ffe369c prio: 21 stack: 2560 I (653) wifi: mode : softAP
- > (3c:71:bf:79:32:e1) I (661) wifi: mode : sta (3c:71:bf:79:32:e0) +
- > softAP (3c:71:bf:79:32:e1) I (665) wifi: mode : softAP
- > (3c:71:bf:79:32:e1) I (669) wifi: set country: cc=CN

*I press reset and boot button of esp32 and set into flash mode*

> rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x3 (DOWNLOAD_BOOT(UART0/UART1/SDIO_REI_REO_V2))

> waiting for download

*Now i upload a blank code to test by holding*

1. Both boot and reset button and released when connecting start
2. boot and released when connecting start
3. reset and released when connecting start

> But none of this working giving an error of :

**A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header**

> please help i cannot find any solution on the internet.

Comment: ISP is flashing method for old AVR chips. I guess you use the Uno's USB chip as USB to TTL Serial adapter, not the Uno as "Arduino as ISP"

Comment: yes i remove the atmega328 p